# Starting rviz tutorial, fail to send markers

Tags: ros, rviz, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I am following rviz tutorial below

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes

I have downloaded the C++ Codes and use catkin to make it as a ros-package. Then I have runned

```
roscore
rosrun rviz rviz
rosrun using_markers basic_shapes
```

But I still not able to find any markers and shapes in rviz.

After I  did `rosrun using_markers basic_shapes`, no information showed in the terminal. Can anyone help me this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/153481/starting-rviz-tutorial,-fail-to-send-markers/) by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2014-04-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At first, Could you check out this page ( http://answers.ros.org/question/147211/a-problem-on-rviz/#149011 ) ? Your problem probably has relate to a TF setting.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on 2014-04-15**:
Thanks! It works!